# How to get frame of a button aspect to the view?

Tags: ios, uiview, mkmapview

I am creating a app and need to get the button's frame respect to the view.

I have a mapview with annotation. While selecting the annotation it shows a callout bubble. That has a button as right accessary view. I have a selector that gets invoked when I tap on that button.

Now I want to get the frame of the button with respect to the view's bound. I want to know where the button is located in the view?

For that I tried:

```
[self.view convertRect:btn.frame fromView:self.view];
```

and

```
[self.view convertRect:btn.frame toView:self.view];
```

I am not getting correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `btn.frame` is relative to its (the button's) super view so passing `self.view` for `fromView` won't give the expected result because `self.view` is not the button's super view (in the case of an annotation callout button).  So that code should be:

```
CGRect rect = [self.view convertRect:btn.frame fromView:btn.superview];
```

Similarly in the `toView` call, the method needs to be called on the button's super view since `btn.frame` is relative to it (not `self.view`):

```
CGRect rect = [btn.superview convertRect:btn.frame toView:self.view];
```